# Ajax "GET" not working in IE 8

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

***The following code is not working in IE8, I have to get data from my controller and need to access the function abcd() and do something, my breakpoint comes out directly without going inside the ajaxcall***

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Transactions/MyList/" + transactionID,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: abcd
});

**function abcd()** {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Did you put another breakpoint *inside* the abcd function?  Also, in IE 8 you may need to add a `dataType:'json'` because... IE. More details would be helpful as well, such as the returned response body, etc

Comment: Yes, I placed a breakpoint on abcd() as well, but as breakpoint hits "$.ajax" call it comes out it is not going inside, that is the reason I am not able to reach abcd().

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @faby- I am using jquery v1.10.2

Comment: Put the breakpoint on the `success: abcd` line. But you are not capturing the return value anyway. It would need to be `success: function(data) {...`

Comment: is your `transactionID` variable what do you expect?

Comment: which error did you get from the call?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get( "//here give the id/class" );
```

For example:

```
$.get( "test.php" );
```

or

```
$.get( "test.php", { name: "abc", time: "2pm" } ); etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that MyList is an action method inside TransactionsController and it returns JsonResult. Correct? Do you AllowGet on your Json result? you can pass a second parameter to the Json result which indicates the AllowGet  behaviour (return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet))...

Plus your abcd method should have one parameter - data - to process what you receive from the call...

Comment: You are right there is a TransactionsController in which I have MyList and it returns JsonResult, but the issue is my breakpoint is not going inside the "ajax" call so how can I hit **"url: "/Transactions/MyList/" + transactionID,"**

Comment: $.get("/Transactions/MyList", { transactionId: _myId }).done(function(data) { // process here }).fail(function(error) {});

Comment: could you please provide me a formatted code it is very difficult to understand...

Comment: $.get("/Transactions/MyList",
            {
                transactionId: myId
            })
        .done(function (data) {
//      process result here      
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

Comment: apparently you can't format the code in a comment... copy it in Visual studio and see what's doing... you just call $.get instead of $.ajax and use the done and fail methods to process the result (in done if the call is done), or the error in fail... it's really simple.

Comment: I have written the code like this:-                  $.get("/Transactions/AttachmentList", {
        url: "/Transactions/AttachmentList/" + transactionID,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: getAttachmentList_onSuccess
    });  but it is not working.

Comment: @Shivam, Your need to [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for the `$.get()` method

Comment: who told you to pass url to get? the first param the "/Transactions/MyList" string is the URL)... also you use $.get, so there is not type property (it's set for you to GET). Make up your mind... you do a POST or a GET? Also you don't need contentType... just use the code I gave you and put a break point in the done method in JavaScript and see what you get. Also make sure your call gets to the server (to the MyList method)

Comment: Thanks!! everyone for your kind support the issue was related with cookies I have removed it and now it is working fine.